# Significance of javascript function name in quotes in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through a javascript file having some functions like this:

```
'form_validation': function(form,error_bin){
        for(var field in form){
            if(field.substr(0,1) != "$"){
                this.validation_messages(field,form,error_bin);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to understand what is the difference between defining a function **with quotes** (like mentioned above) and **without quotes**

**EDIT**: I've also observed that the functions having name in quotes are being called from a different file (like: `ServiceName.functionName()`), while without quotes are being called from the same file.
This is an Angularjs code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are equivalent syntax for object literals. The quotes allow you to use keys that aren't legal variable names, like so:

```
    var foo ={ 'variable name':2}
```

There's nothing significant about the fact that the value assigned to the object key is a function. In JavaScript objects are (almost) just key value pairs of strings and arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has something called ***Objects*** these are link associative array's in other languages. Object have *item*. Each item has a `key`*(name)* and a *`value`*. Key's follow regular JavaScript variable names. You can check valid variable names [here](https://mothereff.in/js-variables). Valid variable names do *not* need to be in quotes. Sometimes, to include special characters, the name is a *string*.

```
my_value  <- Valid
my-value  <- Invalid (needs to be in string)
my value  <- Invalid (needs to be in string)
```

Answer (score 0):

both are same for javascript objects. but you should avoid using quotes as a coding standard.